# Can a Rust struct be parametrized with values instead of types?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and it is not clear to me if it is possible to have a Rust struct parametrized with some values (as well as types).
In order to be more clear, is it possible in Rust to build a struct that mimic the behaviour of this C++ struct?

```
template <int dim, class T>
struct Data
{
  std::array<T, dim> data_;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, you need a [`const` generic parameter](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/03/25/Rust-1.51.0.html#const-generics-mvp).

```rust
struct Data<T, const N: usize> {
    member: [T; N],
}

fn main() {
    let d = Data { member: [0; 6] };
    println!("{:?}", d.member); // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```